# How to add custom hotkeys on Ubuntu 20

Tags: gnome, 20.04, shortcut-keys

I want to add my custom hotkeys on Ubuntu 20, for example: run some .sh script with <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> or read txt file and save output to buffer(to be able to use <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and paste text). I also want to be able to configure this hotkeys through desktop application. Are there any ways of doing that ?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 I can guess from the flag you mean 20.04?

Comment: Please clarify your release.  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 20? or other *specialist* snap only release? but that doesn't fit with Lubuntu as Lubuntu is a *deb* based release and thus uses the *year.month* format and there is no Lubuntu 20. The desktop has a huge impact on the best way to add custom shortcuts (I can provide the manual page for a Lubuntu release, but it won't work on a Ubuntu Core 20 system).  You've tagged 20.04 which helps, but Ubuntu 20 implies *snap* only and Lubuntu isn't available as a snap (GNOME is though which is done differently).  Please be precise & clear.

Comment: Sorry for lubuntu, I meant ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure there are ways of doing that. In any desktop environment, you can assign applications to specific shortcut combinations. That application can be a regular application, but can also be your own .sh script.

You mention Ubuntu in your question title, however added "lubuntu" as a tag, so it is somewhat confusing. In standard Ubuntu, go to "Settings", then "Keyboard Shortcuts". On the bottom of the list, you find a section "Custom shortcuts", where you can add your own shortcuts to run your own commands.

A desktop environment agnostic way to define custom hotkeys involves to use a hotkey daemon such as `xbindkeys` or `sxhkd`. Both of these daemons allow to define hotkeys using simple text configuration files. The advantage of using such daemons is that you can continue to use the same keybindings in a different desktop environment.

Comment: Sorry for lubuntu, you guessed right, I meant ubuntu.
Thanks, a lot for your answer. Xbindkeys way the thing I was looking for.